# Start <li> Elements From right of a Div

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm Facing a problem on styling of

I actually want an output like this

[image]

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li style="border-bottom:1px solid #FFF">HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT US</li>
  <li>GALLERY</li>
  <li>CONTACT US</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-size: 24px;
}

ul li {
  /*float:right;*/
}
```

this is the code it will generate output like this.

[image]

How do i style my code to get output like first image.. Please help me.. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `text-align:right;` on `ul`.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li style="border-bottom:1px solid #FFF">HOME</li>
  <li>ABOUT US</li>
  <li>GALLERY</li>
  <li>CONTACT US</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you.. i tried float:right for <li> . but I didn't tried this one.. My mistake. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

just simply made the ul align center

```
ul {
text-align:center;
}
```